# How to set IE11 default emulating Core

Tags: default, internet-explorer-11, emulation, ie11-developer-tools

how i can set default emulation IE to Edge? In F12 i have selected IE7 and i dont know how return Edge.

[image: IE11 Developer Tools default emulating mode]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The easiest way to get your page to render in Edge mode is to include a DOCTYPE on the top of your HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

If you are testing your page locally or on the intranet, you may have to change your Compatibility view settings. These can be found in:

```
"Tools" (Alt+T) -> "Compatibility View Settings" -> And uncheck "Display Intranet Sites in Compatibility View"
```

You can also include the X-UA-Compatible  tag, which will force the page to EDGE mode.

More information on X-UA-Compatible: http://modern.ie/en-us/performance/how-to-use-x-ua-compatible

If you have any more questions, you visit http://Modern.ie

Comment: This is a question about the client (not server) - we would like to save your emulation setting so if we return to the page it's remembered.

Answer (score 0):

As with MS and specifically IE habit, it's a little more complicated. Look at this [article](https://www.modern.ie/en-us/f12), which refers to [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn321457.aspx). In a result is thus several ways to achieve what you need.